# JAXB Element without attribute

Tags: xml, jaxb

I'm working with JAXB and need to generate a XML code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!--Created with JFLAP 6.4.-->
<structure>
    <type>fa</type>
    <automaton>
        <!--The list of states.-->
        <state id="0" name="q0">
            <x>160.0</x>
            <y>151.0</y
            <initial/>                 <!-- This what I want-->
        </state>
        <state id="1" name="q1">
            <x>369.0</x>
            <y>94.0</y>
            <final/>                   <!-- This what I want-->
        </state>
        <!--The list of transitions.-->
        <transition>
            <from>0</from>
            <to>1</to>
            <read>a</read>
        </transition>
    </automaton>
</structure>
```

As you can see, I wanna know how to create a simple @XmlElement without @XmlAttribute, but in my code, I got:

```
private boolean initial = false;
private boolean final   = false;

@XmlElement(name="initial")
public void setInitial(boolean val) {
    this.initial = val;
}

@XmlElement(name="final")
public void setFinal(boolean val) {
    this.final = val;
}
```

This way, I got a XML like this:

```
<state id="0" name="q0">
        <x>0.0</x>
        <y>0.0</y>
        <final>false</final>
        <initial>true</initial>
</state>
<state id="1" name="q1">
        <x>0.0</x>
        <y>0.0</y>
        <final>true</final>
        <initial>false</initial>
</state>
```

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following and leverage an `XmlAdapter` to convert a `Boolean` to an empty object to get the desired XML representation.

### Java Model

**Root**

The property is `boolean`, but we will make the field `Boolean` so we can apply an `XmlAdapter` to it.  We will also specify that we want JAXB to map to the field (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    private Boolean foo = false;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    private Boolean bar = false;

    public boolean isFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(boolean foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public boolean isBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(boolean bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**BooleanAdapter**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<BooleanAdapter.AdaptedBoolean, Boolean> {

    public static class AdaptedBoolean {
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(AdaptedBoolean v) throws Exception {
        return null != v;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedBoolean marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        if(v) {
            return new AdaptedBoolean();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

Below is some demo code that you can run to see that everything works.

**Demo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root foo = new Root();
        foo.setFoo(true);
        foo.setBar(false);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <foo/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you said and it was perfect. Except for the fact that I wanted to save <final/> in file and the name of the variable could not be "final" HAHAHA. So, I had to rename it to "final_" and after open the file and replace with "final". 
Thanks for all!

Comment: @GuiCavi - You can use `@XmlElement(name="final")` along with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to get the desired output.

Comment: @GuiCavi - I'm happy I could help.  If this solved your problem you can click the checkbox icon next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake an empty node by setting an empty string, for this you need to turn your `boolean`s to `String`s.

```
@XmlRootElement
public static  class Structure {
    @XmlElement String type;
    @XmlElement Automaton automaton;
    public Structure() { automaton = new Automaton(); }
    Structure(String t) { this(); type = t; }
}

public static class Automaton {
    @XmlElement List<State> state;
    public Automaton() { state = new ArrayList<>(); }
    State addState(State s) {state.add(s); return s;};
}

public static class State {
    @XmlAttribute String id, name;
    @XmlElement double x, y;
    @XmlElement String initial;
    @XmlElement(name="final") String final_;
    public State() {};
    State(String id, String n, double x, double y)
    {this.id = id; name = n; this.x = x; this.y = y;};
}
```

Create some data and marshal it:

```
@Test
public void jaxbEmptyEmlements() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(Structure.class);
    Marshaller m = c.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    Structure o = new Structure("fa");
    o.automaton.addState(new State("0", "q0", 160d, 151d)).initial = "";
    o.automaton.addState(new State("1", "q1", 369d, 94d)).final_ = "";
    m.marshal(o, System.out);
}
```

This will output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<structure>
    <type>fa</type>
    <automaton>
        <state id="0" name="q0">
            <x>160.0</x>
            <y>151.0</y>
            <initial></initial>
        </state>
        <state id="1" name="q1">
            <x>369.0</x>
            <y>94.0</y>
            <final></final>
        </state>
    </automaton>
</structure>
```

Note that `<initial></initial>` is the same as `<initial/>`, same for `final`.

<strike>Alternatively you could rethink the node for the state type and make an element `<state-type>` and set it with the value an enum, for example `enum StateType { INITIAL, FINAL}` or simply set it to the strings `initial` or `final`.</strike>

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for it. My intention is create a XML file to open on JFLAP. I'll try your idea and give a feedback!

Comment: @GuiCavi, you're welcome, hope it helps you solve your problem!

Comment: I tried what you said, but JFLAP still can't open. But thanks anyway =D

Comment: @GuiCavi, don't know what you exactly did, but the file opens just fine (see the screen shot). Anyways It seems that you could solve you problem and that's cool :D

Comment: Wow... well, I really don't know what was wrong, but it works well. Thank you for your help and now I know it works. =D